# How can I change the code so it can solve the model?

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization

It is not possible for Julia to solve it when I use `a[i, j] = 1`. how can i get julia to solve this problem?

```
using JuMP
using GLPK

u = [1 2 3 ; 1 2 3 ; 1 2 3]

m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
    @variable(m, a[1:3,1:3], Bin)
    @objective(m, Max, sum(u[i,j]*a[i,j] for i=1:3, j=1:3))
    @constraint(m, [a[i,j]=1], sum(a[i:j][i:j]) == 1)
    solution = optimize!(m)
    opt_value = value.(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

in the line

```
 @constraint(m, [a[i,j]=1], sum(a[i:j][i:j]) == 1)
```

1) You're trying to set a variable, not to test equality, instead use

```
a[i,j] == 1
```

2) i and j are undefined. Without a minimal example to run, I would say according to the previous line of your code, I would say something like

```
sum(<what-to-sum-here> for i=1:3, j=1:3)
```

Or loop on the list of index you want to use if not the proper one.

Comment: thanks. But then the problem is that it want me to define i and j in the sum.

Comment: It would not solve the problem correctly then. The legal solutions are:
(a[1,1], a[2,2], a[3,3] = 1) or 
(a[1,2], a[3,3] = 1) or
(a[1,3] = 1)